# spam problem (inbound mail)

Tags: email

I do have problems with some inbound e-mail processed by mail to activity. Some spammer got hands on the e-mail address for e-mail processing to activity. I have listed the e-mail address displayed by civi to the pop-mail-boxes spam filter (spamassassin):

```
preference  value
blacklist_from yxz@spam.com
```

however the spam still goes to civi's inbound mail...

To do further inverstigation I need the e-mail header, which is not displayed in civicrm U/I.

Is there a way to see the header, probably with a mysql statement. I think it should be somewhere in the database...

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

A copy of the raw email is in the CiviMail.processed folder under the "custom" folder. Depending on the CMS you are using the location is different, but e.g. for Drupal it's usually sites/default/files/civicrm